# Is it ok to ask questions that could be solved with SEDE queries?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

If there is some information in Stack Overflow that I want to know and definitely can be done with the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries), should I ask it here?

Comment: Like all Qs anywhere on the network, you should try your hardest to answer the Q for yourself before asking others to donate their time. Take a whack at it and come back to us.

Comment: Why would you like to ask it, if you already know a way to answer it yourself?

Comment: Maybe I know the way to answer it, but just don't know how to use SEDE

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've written a SEDE query to resolve your question. [You can see it run here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1162815):

[image: SEDE Answer]

On a more serious note, I think this is completely fine from time to time if you're having trouble with a query or if you need one-time data (something like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339661/232439)). But if you're posting weekly just asking for statistics without bothering to try to learn the SQL or how SEDE works, you will likely start to earn downvotes/close votes.

Comment: +1 Your last statement probably applies across the entire Stack Exchange network. If you keep posting on-topic questions about the same topic/theme, at some point the regular followers will get tired of it and start downvoting/closing your questions.

Comment: Extra links: [SEDE tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial), [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) and the [data-explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer) tag on MSE.

Comment: @user000001 the difference between main sites and meta is set of users - on meta there is significantly smaller set of users that answer questions and it is *very hard* to ask many questions and not have you name remembered by everyone... On the main site it is quite possible to ask many questions on topics that don't intersect and essentially have new set of people to answer each one (some make mistake posting several question on the same topic and that leads to *interesting outcomes* )